# Unable to load DLL 'OraOps12.dll

Tags: asp.net, oracle, oracleclient

I build and publish my project with oracle client 12.1.0 and deploy it to server which has 11.1.0 client but I got this error. How could I solve this?
Please help me ?
My Error -

> Unable to load DLL 'OraOps12.dll
>
> The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007007E)
>                     at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OpsInit.CheckVersionCompatibility(String
>   version)    at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleInit.Initialize()    at
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection..cctor()

Comment: You can't build for one version and publish to another, either you build with 11 or update server to 12

Answer (score 0):

Its too late but i have this issue even i have installed both 32bit and 64bit oracle drivers. Just i change the Identity in `ApplicationPool` and Enable 32 and well then its working.

[image]

Comment: If the rest of your app is 64-bit this creates another issue... now you get DLL wrong format error.

Answer (score 0):

if you installed Oracle client Xcopy version you should install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable  (2008, 2010 or 2013)

Answer (score 0):

Select the application (IIS) pool used, change Enable 32bits to true, OK and then false. Works for me.